# What's the best method for preparing a smoked cod roe breakfast?

Tags: eggs, breakfast, cod

I have some good smoked cod roe that I want to create a breakfast dish with.

I have no idea what to do with the cod roe though - I've never used it before. Do I slice it? Fry it? Spread it?

Ideally it would be toast, fried eggs and the cod roe plus whatever else would go well to make a breakfast treat for my girlfriend (who's a chef so it has to be good :))

Answer (score 1):

Try using it as you would smoked Salmon and thinly slice or spread it over a bagel with cream cheese or slice it and stir it with scrambled eggs right before they are done or serving it with hollandaise egg